# Not getting ScrollView for kivy

Tags: python, kivy, scrollview

Iam creating an app so that my code is given below but **why Iam not getting ScrollView What's wrong with this code can anybody explain me.**

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
root1 = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height))
root2 = FloatLayout()
def c(a):
    root1.remove_widget(root2)
    layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
    layout1 = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
    layout1.bind(minimum_height=layout1.setter('height'))
    for i in range(100):
        btn = Button(text=str(i), size_hint_y=None, height=40)
        layout1.add_widget(btn)
    layout2=GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
    b1=Button(text='hi')
    layout2.add_widget(b1)
    layout.add_widget(layout2)
    layout.add_widget(layout1)
    root1.add_widget(layout)
b=Image(source='/storage/emulated/0/Photo Editor/Polish_20210216_162256244.png')
root2.add_widget(b)
root1.add_widget(root2)
Clock.schedule_once(c, 2)
runTouchApp(root1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using a `GridLayout` inside another `GridLayout`, but that is the problem. If you use two of them, each must be using `minimum_height`. Just add the line:

```
layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
```